# Drawing largers points with X11

Tags: c, x11

I know X11 has XDrawPoints for drawing multiple points in a batch, but I'd like to have slightly larger points sometimes (useful if you're eg: drawing a line through them), but can't find any way to draw larger points without doing something kludgy like drawing a tiny filled rectangle, or zero-length line with endcaps.

Is there a reasonable way to set the point size that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

A point is a single pixel in Xlib. But XFillArcs() would let you create a list of XArc structures that describe small circles. Then you can scale these circles to any radius by setting XArc.width and XArc.height.

Comment: Yeah I can use XFillRectangles to get large square points, the problem with doing things like that is it at least doubles the amount of data to be sent over to the X server, which can matter when you're doing X11 tunneling.

Comment: Then you should use GLX, as you can update OpenGL's state to handle this without sending more data per point. Normally people use GLFloat coordinates, but it should be fine to use GLshort coordinates. (GLbyte might work too, but not be useful). GLX should encapsulate the request without modifying the data, thus saving you significant bandwidth when you are tunneling.

Comment: OpenGL is undesirable too because most VNC servers don't suport it =(

Comment: Well if you are using using VNC then sending extra data to X is not a big deal as VNC's bandwidth is proportional to the number of pixels you change and not related to the chattiness of x11 protocol you access through xlib or xcb. It is possible to use GLX in Xvnc with Mesa SWX11. And I use x11vnc on my desktop even with GLX apps. The VNC client doesn't handle animation in GL very well as you can imagine, but it eventually settles on the right image.  So which is it, are you using X or VNC ?